RP5 problems with network connection
I have been experiencing various issues with connecting to my new RP5 over my wifi network. Using systemctl the following error appears repeatedly during those periods:
raspberry kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd022 fail, reason -52
The Pi is mostly working but theses random network failures seem to point so some hardware fragility. Any ideas?

I searched through my Pi 5 logs and found two sets of this message (about 5 weeks apart over a 60 day uptime), each time it's repeated four times (the "chanspec" for each set is 0xd022, 26, 2a, 2e) within 1 second and followed by ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_p2p_send_action_frame: Unknown Frame: category 0xa, action 0x8.    I can't say whether there were any connection problems at the time (it's generally fine).  You might want to provide more context from the log and detail exactly what you mean by "various issues with connecting to".

See also https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=367466

I am using the RP5 headless to explore aarch64 assembly as my Mac is an old Intel machine. I have had no issues whatsoever with using the Pi without any attached USB drives but when I connect an SSD I frequently find that on booting the Pi is not visible on the network. The problem appears sporadic and right now all is OK and I’m just leaving it running all the time.

There is a reported bug in a Broadcom driver - see bugzilla.redhat.com Bug 2302577 - wpa_supplicant 2.11 breaks WPA2-PSK / WPA3-SAE authentication on Linux' brcmfmac

I guess it could be that, although the symptoms do not look the same and it does not explain the Pi specific report from the forum link in my other comment (which more closely resembles your problem), since it predates wpa_supplicant 2.11 (released 7/20/24).  Presumably you are running Arch since 2.11 never made it into Rpi OS (or most other distros).  Did you try downgrading to 2.10?

I don’t appear to have a problem when I hot-plug a drive and I’ve decided to keep the Pi on constantly so for the time being that’s good enough.  I’ve posted this message on the RP Forum  as well.  But at least the problem doesn’t appear to be user error :)
